# How to speed up lookup method in java?

Tags: java, weblogic

I need to lookup 100 weblogic jms queues. But my program needs 100 seconds to do it, and I need to speed it up. Is there a way to do it?

```
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "your_host:port");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
     Destination queue = (Destination) ctx.lookup("jndi name of your queue");
}
```

Comment: Err, what is 'context'? Is this JNDI? LDAP? What?

Comment: @EJP Yes, sorry. I am looking up a destination by establishing a JNDI context.

Comment: It's possible that this is more suited to code-review.stackexchange

Comment: Well there is no setSpeed() method to magically make performance problems go away, so you will first need to figure out where the performance problem is actually coming from; likely not code. At this point I can easily assume you have to break through three firewalls, a proxy server and a faulty switch on the other side of a decaying ocean cable which is what making this slow.

Comment: You can play with your servers memory settings but it will be very difficult to pinpoint why this particular query is slow